# Andalé Mono font license

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-licensing

I am considering Andalé Mono font for a website, but I do not know the license.
I did not see mention of the license here:

[http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalé_Mono](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Andal%C3%A9_Mono)

Where can I find the license for this font?

Comment: looks like proprietary http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web

Answer (score 1):

It says [right there in the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andal%C3%A9_Mono#Retail_versions):

> The Andale Mono typeface family sold by Ascender Corporation includes bold and italics variants, in TrueType format. This version supports WGL character set.
>
> Andalé Mono is also sold by Monotype, it does not include italics, and does not support Greek, Cyrillic, and most Latin Extended-A/B characters found in the Ascender version. It is available in OpenType CFF, TrueType, PostScript formats. However, Monotype has also produced language-specific variants of Andalé Mono in Cherokee (Andalé Mono Cherokee), Cyrillic (Andalé Mono Cyrillic), Greek (Andalé Mono Greek), Hebrew (Andalé Mono Hebrew) character sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to purchase a webfont licence, look to font vendors like [monotype](https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/andale-mono) and [myfonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/andale-mono/)